# How to express the definition of a generated subalgebra as an equation?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, probability, abstract-algebra

**Definition:** Let $A$ be an associative algebra and $S$ a subset of $A$. The **subalgebra** generated by $S$ is the collection of all linear combinations of $\mathbf{s_1s_2\cdots s_k,\ s_i}\in S$.

**My attempt:**

The subalgebra $A_S$ generated by the $S$ which is a subset of associative algebra $A$ is :
$$A_S \equiv \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\prod_{j=1}^m\mathbf{s}_{\sigma_i(j)}\ \bigg\vert \ \forall n,m\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$
where $\sigma_i$ can be any sequence of $S$.

by sequence I mean any way to putting element in $S$ together with considering order and can be repeat. for example, $\{\mathbf{a,b}\}$ can have $\mathbf{aba^2b^3aab}$ by mapping 1 to a, 2 to b, 3 to a, 4 to a, 5 to b...

Comment: By an (associative) algebra, do you mean _algebra over a field_? In that case, recall that the underlying structure is simply a vector space (what makes it an algebra is just the extra bilinear product it is equipped with). Since the underlying structure of $A$ is a vector space and $S$ is a subset of it, the notion of "subalgebra generated by $S$" is the same as equipping the bilinear product on the _linear (vector) subspace_ generated by $S$ (ie, the linear span of $S$)

Comment: @Prasun Biswas Thank you! that make much more sense!